# separate repaints in awt

Tags: java, awt

The "Painting in AWT and Swing" docs state the following.

*"If multiple calls to repaint() occur on a component before the initial repaint request is processed, the multiple requests may be collapsed into a single call to update()."*

Is it possible to change this behavior in a component so that multiple calls to repaint never get collapsed into a single call?

EDIT: The docs further state this, "The algorithm for determining when multiple requests should be collapsed is implementation-dependent."

My problem is I'm on a mobile platform that does separate calls to repaint and I'm trying to replicate the behavior on the desktop.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Sounds like you're updating the state in the paint-method... which sounds like a *really* bad idea.

Comment: Why would you want to change this behavior? It seems the best way to handle a backlog of repaint calls. To aioobe: that was my thought exactly, that he has program logic occurring in a paint method.

Comment: Get an emulator for your mobile device instead of trying to replicate it on another implementation. It will never behave truly same there.  (And ideally, your code should not depend on the number of calls to `update` or `paint()` or `paintComponent()`.)

Answer (score 0):

I fear the paint algorithm is pretty hardcoded in swing/awt and they only offer different hooks for different purposes. You can use use [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintImmediately%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) method in swing which would offer what you want, but sadly there doesn't seem to be an awt equivalent. You could try mixing awt/swing, but that's usually not recommended and may lead to strange behavior in some cases as I hear

PS: And for people asking WHY you'd want this: Some apps (mostly games) need synchronous redraws to ensure that their visual appearance keeps up with the internal state - afaik the JScrollbar also uses it internally for example (I haven't looked at the code in question, so take this with a grain of salt - I do understand though why it could be useful in that particular case)

Comment: well I see that only with only one implementations for one Custom TreeTable

Comment: @mKorbel I heard somewhere that JScrollBar uses it internally and I can follow the logic behind it, but I haven't looked at the code so that's why I didn't put it as a definite fact there - but probably not especially well formulated - I hope the added note makes it clearer :)

Comment: The mobile platform I'm working on unfortunately doesn't support Swing.  It only supports AWT.  The platform I'm using makes separate calls to repaint so I'm trying to replicate the behavior on the desktop using only AWT.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you have some long running task that is looping an not updating the GUI as you expect it to. This would be because you are blocking the Event Dispatch Thread so Swing can't repaint itself.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency in Swing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html). Use the SwingWorker for the long running task to you don't block the EDT and then you can publish results and required and they will be painted as expected.

Or if you problem is with animation, then use a Swing Timer. The tutorial also has a section on timers.